# vlfeat nmake: fatal error U1073: don't know how to make "msvcr100.dll"

Tags: nmake, vlfeat

I have downloaded vlfeat source code. I am trying make file using nmake (Microsoft Visual Studio command) to use vlfeat.

The command I have given is:

> nmake /f Makefile.mak ARCH=win32

It gives the following error.

> NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '"C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC
>   \redist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.CRT\msvcr100.dll"' Stop.

Please help me to fix it.

**Configurations**
Windows 7 32 bit OS
VLFeat version: 0.9.17
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express

Regards
Sridhar

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the argument to nmake in quotes:

```
nmake /f Makefile.mak "ARCH=win32"
```

but as you have not given details of the makefile in your question its hard to help without more details.

Comment: I think this is totally irrelevant